# Texture to Vertex

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I have four separate square made of 12 vertex. I have a texture image. I want to add the texture to square. I added like my algorithm is like

```
vertexID % 4 == 0 => Texture Coordinates (0,0)  
vertexID % 4 == 1 => Texture Coordinates (0,1) 
vertexID % 4 == 2 => Texture Coordinates (1,1) 
vertexID % 4 == 3 => Texture Coordinates (1,0)
```

rather than this i want to add randomly. Simply means texture coordinates has to be random means if first square is aligned as above second square has to be aligned flipped third can be 90 degrees rotated. I hope we can do it by if else statement in shader any other optimized way to add texture for this scenario

Comment: What are you asking specifically? It's certainly possible to do this. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Currently I am doing it by If else statement. Rather conditional statement any method to add textures randomly to four vertex.

Comment: For an example I can write conditional statement for flipping also and for 90 degree rotation. Any optimized way rather than conditional statement